# Moving Web Application To Web Hosting/Web Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web

Let's imagine that I have finished web application made with JavaEE. This web application contains login system but in the end its very basic web application. I used GlassFish 3.1.2.2.

I would like to know that once finished web application I would like to move/deploy this web application to my web hosting/web server, let's say to Bluehost. What measures I need to make, how they are done and what requirements there are?

I have been searching around the internet but not found any single page that could answer to my question.

Comment: I wanted to know the idea of doing such task and some instructions. I thought there would be some universal way to do it, but it seems that its specified based on web hosting??

Comment: Well generally you only need to create a WAR file but it will depend how the hosting work, if they provide Tomcat, Glassfish, JBoss, etc. It also depend if you want your application ROOT etc etc. I think they will help you much better!

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I will definitely be in contact with my web hosting and ask in details about it. However I understand know that I have to do WAR file and to deploy it and I think I can manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to package as WAR file and deploy on the server.

The best and free to use is openshift. It comes with TOMCAT which you can use. Remember tomcat doesn't support EJBs.

Comment: I have Tomcat but I'm not using it in that particular web application. I need to find for Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

You're in demand of a provider that supports *Java Servlet and JavaServer Pages*.  Package your application as a *war* file and upload it to a [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) instance, or any other servlet container.